# mysql create view of two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

i am new to mysql i want to create view of my two tables those are related to eachother as i want to show professor name on view not his id.

my first table

```
lectures ( lc_id, lcname, lccost, lcdescription, lcduration, lcstart, lc_image, lc_prid, status)
```

---

second table is

```
professors(pr_id, prname, prgender, prage, prphone, prabout, prqualification, pr_image, status)
```

in lc_prid professor id data will store so i want after join professor name with behalf of it id on lectures and want to see it as view to get it all together.

what i tried to use join but seems idk how does join work.

Comment: Show the query that you have tried.

Comment: select * from lectures join select * from professor on lc_pid = pr_id